# TabLayout crashing after updating android studio to 2.3 version

Tags: android, android-studio-2.3

I have already searched this issue but everyone says that it got resolved in android support library 23.2.1. But i am using 23.2.1 only still my App is crashing.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Tab belongs to a different
>   TabLayout.
>                                                                                     at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.addTab(TabLayout.java:433)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.populateFromPagerAdapter(TabLayout.java:772)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.access$2700(TabLayout.java:124)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$PagerAdapterObserver.onChanged(TabLayout.java:2008)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:37)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(PagerAdapter.java:282)

My Project Dependencies :

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile('cn.trinea.android.view.autoscrollviewpager:android-auto-scroll-view-pager:1.1.2') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile project(':PayU-release')
    compile project(':pgwrapper')
    compile project(':CustomBrowser-release')
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.16.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.6.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'
    compile('cn.trinea.android.view.autoscrollviewpager:android-auto-scroll-view-pager:1.1.2') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile 'org.lucasr.twowayview:twowayview:0.1.4'
    compile 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:library:1.6.0@aar'
    compile 'com.payu.magicretry:magicretry:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
}
```

Comment: have you tried with the latest support lib 25.3.1?

Comment: No i didn't try.. will that solve my problem?

Comment: Try update all com.android.support libraries to 25.3.1

Comment: ok i Will try that thing..

Comment: I tired with that but my app started crashing some where else.. any other solution?

Comment: post some code or StackTrace of crash in order to help you

Comment: Already there in the question it self...

Comment: Thanks @Raghunandan , Zarul It actually worked after updating all the support libraries.